# addblogging.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null for text area

Tags: javascript, html

I want to read `textarea` value using JavaScript.

Here is my code:

I use JavaScript in `async` way. Hopefully we can use `textarea` inside the form. This is not a fault.

```js
function validate() {
    let title = document.getElementById("title").value;
    document.write(title);

    let textarea = document.querySelector("#textarea1").value;
    document.write(textarea);

     let image = document.getElementById("myimage").value;
     document.write(image)


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>AddBlogging</title>
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="AddBloggsstylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous" />

    <script src="js/addblogging.js"></script>


</head>

<body>

    <hr />
    <div class="container">
        <form class="form-group" action="AddBloggs.html" onsubmit="return validate()">
            <h2>Blogger Page</h2>
            <label>Title</label>
            <input type="text" name="Title" id="title" lass="form-control" /><br />
            <label>TextArea</label>
            <textarea name="comment" id="textarea1" placeholder="Text" class=" form-control "></textarea>
            <br />
            <label>Image</label>
            <input type="file" name="myImage" id="myimage" accept="image/png, image/gif, image/jpeg " class="form-control " />
            <br />

            <br />
            <br />

            <!-- <input type="submit " value="submit " class="btn btn-success " /> -->
            <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-success " />
            <input type="reset " value="reset " class="btn btn-info " />
        </form>
    </div>
    <hr />

    <div class="container ">
        <div class="row row-cols-auto ">

            <div class="col ">
                <div class="rightcolumn ">
                    <h2>TITLE HEADING</h2>
                    <h5>Title description, Sep 2, 2017</h5>
                    <div class="fakeimg " style="height:200px; ">Image</div>
                    <p>Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>




</body>

</html>
```

but I got an error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null`

[Error details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSRu0.png)

any help regrading this error.For Javascript I use async ways...So script loading I hope it is not a problem.

Comment: Okye sir, how to accept it....do you know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That erros is not about `textarea`. It's about `document.write`. After this line `let title = document.getElementById("title").value` you've used `document.write` that delete all current HTML, so you don't have any `textarea` or something else.

Notice to definition of `write()`:

> The write() method is mostly used for testing: If it is used after an HTML document is fully loaded, it will **delete all** existing HTML.

So, first you need to read **all value**, concatenate them and **then** write to documnet:

```js
function validate() {
    let title = document.getElementById("title").value;
    let textarea = document.querySelector("#textarea1").value;

    let image = document.getElementById("myimage").value;

    document.write(title + "\n" + textarea + "\n" + image);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>AddBlogging</title>
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="AddBloggsstylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous" />

    <script src="js/addblogging.js"></script>


</head>

<body>

    <hr />
    <div class="container">
        <form class="form-group" action="AddBloggs.html" onsubmit="return validate()">
            <h2>Blogger Page</h2>
            <label>Title</label>
            <input type="text" name="Title" id="title" lass="form-control" /><br />
            <label>TextArea</label>
            <textarea name="comment" id="textarea1" placeholder="Text" class=" form-control "></textarea>
            <br />
            <label>Image</label>
            <input type="file" name="myImage" id="myimage" accept="image/png, image/gif, image/jpeg " class="form-control " />
            <br />

            <br />
            <br />

            <!-- <input type="submit " value="submit " class="btn btn-success " /> -->
            <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-success " />
            <input type="reset " value="reset " class="btn btn-info " />
        </form>
    </div>
    <hr />

    <div class="container ">
        <div class="row row-cols-auto ">

            <div class="col ">
                <div class="rightcolumn ">
                    <h2>TITLE HEADING</h2>
                    <h5>Title description, Sep 2, 2017</h5>
                    <div class="fakeimg " style="height:200px; ">Image</div>
                    <p>Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>




</body>

</html>
```